# Permutation or change of coordinates such that $ax+by+cz=1$ holds with the consideration $c>0$.

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

We say that three positive integers $x,y,z$ are coprime if there exist three integers $a,b,c$ such that $$ax+by+cz=1$$

Here $a,b,c$ have different signs, i.e., at least one of them is negative.

I am asking if there is any permutation or change of coordinates such that the above equation holds with the consideration $c>0$.